# the <a> element with empty href in ng-template is not calling the javascript function

Tags: angular6

I have this template

```
<ng-template #thumbnailTemplate let-context="thumbnailContext">

      <div id="{{context.divId}}"> 
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" (click)="showEnlargeImage(context)"> 
          <img id="{{context.imgId}}" src="{{context.imgSrc}}"/> <!-- this will have width, height=80-->
        </button>
        <a *ngIf="this.isEditing" href="#" id="{{context.closeId}}" onClick="deleteThumbnailfromContainer(context)"></a> 
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

The `<a>` is shown dynamically depending on the value of `isEditing`. This part works fine. On clicking `<a>`, I expect that `deleteThumbnailfromContainer` gets called and the page doesn't redirect because `deleteThumbnailfromContainer` returns `false`. But the page gets refreshed. I also think that `deleteThumbnailfromContainer` is not getting called because `deleteThumbnailfromContainer` has an `alert` which doesn't pop up.

```
deleteThumbnailfromContainer(thumbnailContext:ThumbnailContext){

    console.log("delete thumbnail  clicked ");
    let index = this.thumbnailContainerRef.indexOf(thumbnailContext.viewRefId);
    console.log("deleting index "+index);
    this.thumbnailContainerRef.remove(index);
    alert();

    return false; 
  }
```

The generated html looks like follows (looks alright to me).

```
<a _ngcontent-c9="" href="#" onclick="deleteThumbnailfromContainer(context)" id="close-button-1"></a>
```

I can't figure out why the code isn't working correctly here.

Comment: Try `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: why the "#" doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this out.

```
    <a  *ngIf="this.isEditing" href="javascript:void(0)" 
    (click)="deleteThumbnailfromContainer(context)" id="close-button-1"></a>
```

Comment: There is no problem with  "#" , I think you face this issue due to  "onclick".  Angular  use (click) instead. of onclick. [link](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)